# How to understand this C++ syntax?

Tags: c++, syntax

```
template <class F, class... Args>
void for_each_argument(F f, Args&&... args) {
    (void)(int[]){(f(forward<Args>(args)), 0)...};
}
```

I saw this code somewhere, but how does it turn out to be do `f` for each in `args`. What is going on here.

Comment: Nowadays you can write `(f(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);` which looks somewhat more sane.

Comment: @nwp I still can't understand the mechanism there.

Comment: Look up "variadic templates" and "parameter pack expansion". You might need [a book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).